# What is the role of keepdims in Numpy (Python)?

Tags: python, numpy

When I use `np.sum`, I encountered a parameter called `keepdims`. After looking up [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html), I still cannot understand the meaning of `keepdims`.

> `keepdims`: bool, optional
>
> If this is set to True, the axes which are reduced are left in the result as dimensions with size one. With this option, the result will broadcast correctly against the original arr.

I will appreciate it if anyone can make some sense of this with a simple example.

Answer (score 41):

Consider a small 2d array:

```
In [180]: A=np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
In [181]: A
Out[181]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

Sum across rows; the result is a (3,) array

```
In [182]: A.sum(axis=1)
Out[182]: array([ 6, 22, 38])
```

But to sum (or divide) `A` by the `sum` requires reshaping

```
In [183]: A-A.sum(axis=1)
...
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,4) (3,) 
In [184]: A-A.sum(axis=1)[:,None]   # turn sum into (3,1)
Out[184]: 
array([[ -6,  -5,  -4,  -3],
       [-18, -17, -16, -15],
       [-30, -29, -28, -27]])
```

If I use `keepdims`, "the result will broadcast correctly against" `A`.

```
In [185]: A.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)   # (3,1) array
Out[185]: 
array([[ 6],
       [22],
       [38]])
In [186]: A-A.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)
Out[186]: 
array([[ -6,  -5,  -4,  -3],
       [-18, -17, -16, -15],
       [-30, -29, -28, -27]])
```

If I sum the other way, I don't need the `keepdims`.  Broadcasting this sum is automatic: `A.sum(axis=0)[None,:]`.  But there's no harm in using `keepdims`.

```
In [190]: A.sum(axis=0)
Out[190]: array([12, 15, 18, 21])    # (4,)
In [191]: A-A.sum(axis=0)
Out[191]: 
array([[-12, -14, -16, -18],
       [ -8, -10, -12, -14],
       [ -4,  -6,  -8, -10]])
```

If you prefer, these actions might make more sense with `np.mean`, normalizing the array over columns or rows.  In any case it can simplify further math between the original array and the sum/mean.

Comment: this is a nice answer

Comment: In the same example, can you elaborate these two differences? >>> A.sum(axis=0, keepdims=False)
array([12, 15, 18, 21])
>>> A.sum(axis=0, keepdims=True)
array([[12, 15, 18, 21]])

Comment: @MonaJalal.  `A` is 2d.  The first sum is 1d, (4,).  the second sum is 2d (1,4).  It summed axis 0, but kept it around as a size (1,) dimension, rather than squeeze it out.

Answer (score 5):

You can keep the dimension with `"keepdims=True"` if you sum a matrix 
For example:

```
import numpy as np
x  = np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
x.shape
# (2, 3)

np.sum(x, keepdims=True).shape
# (1, 1)
np.sum(x, keepdims=True)
# array([[21]]) <---the reault is still a 1x1 array

np.sum(x, keepdims=False).shape
# ()
np.sum(x, keepdims=False)
# 21 <--- the result is an integer with no dimesion
```

Answer (score 3):

keepdims = true; In this case your dimensions of the array(Matrix) will be saved. That means the result you get is "broadcasted" correctly against the Array you are trying to implement the methods.

when you ignore it is just an ordinary array with no more dimensions.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.rand(4,3)

#Output for below statement: (3,)
print((np.sum(x, axis=0)).shape)

#Output for below statement: (1, 3)
print((np.sum(x, axis=0, keepdims=True)).shape)
```

Answer (score -3):

keepdims = True, is used for matching dimensions of matrix. If we left this False then it will show error of dimension error.
You can see it while calculating softmax entropy