# Python numpy sum (-1)

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I want to normalize a matrix A. I came across this code:

```
A_norm = (A / np.sqrt((A ** 2).sum(-1))[..., np.newaxis]).astype(np.float32)
```

We're subtracting a mean of 0 here, I assume. My problem is the denominator. We're taking the square root of something we've squared and summed, but I don't understand what.

Specifically, what does this do:

```
np.sqrt((A ** 2).sum(-1))[..., np.newaxis]
```

Comment: Square-root of summed up values along the last axis. That `[..., np.newaxis]`  basically keeps the number of dims same that was reduced by the summing. Alternative is using [keepdims` with summing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html). On the ellipsis `...` to extend the last dim, see [`here`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40383002/3293881). More info on ellipsis : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772124/what-does-the-python-ellipsis-object-do

Comment: Recent question on `keepdims`, with example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40927156/what-the-role-of-keepdims-in-python

Comment: [`np.newaxis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#numpy.newaxis) is something worth figuring out even though it’s confusing. It’s basically Numpy’s answer to the question, “How do we convert rank-1 arrays (vectors) to rank-2 and rank-3 and rank-N arrays (matrix-like arrays, volumes, N-dimensional volumes, respectively)”. Experiment with the following in Python (IPython, Jupyter Notebook, etc.): `np.random.rand(3)[:, np.newaxis]` and `np.random.rand(3,3)[:, :, np.newaxis]`, replacing the colors with `...` and replacing `np.newaxis` with `None`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have

```
np.sqrt((A ** 2).sum(-1))
```

which can be decomposed as

```
B = A**2
C = B.sum(-1)
D = np.sqrt(C)
```

where `C` is the row-sum of `B`, which has been flatten by the operation (the column sum would have been `B.sum(0)`) and `D` is the entrywise squareroot of `C`.

For `A` to be correctly normalized, we need the denominator to be correctly shaped, so as to divide the *k*th row of `A` by the *k*th term of `D`. Thus we must explicitly reshape the flatten result of  `np.sqrt(C)` as being a column vector as follows

```
D = np.sqrt(C)[..., np.newaxis]
```