# caculate 3-D array numpy value without loops base on exist 3-D array numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

i have a 3D-np.array s like this

```
s = np.array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
               [ 3,  4,  5],
               [ 6,  7,  8]],

              [[ 9, 10, 11],
               [12, 13, 14],
               [15, 16, 17]],

              [[18, 19, 20],
               [21, 22, 23],
               [24, 25, 26]]], dtype=float)
```

call (x, y, z) id coordinate of a element of array, how could i use numpy to caculate `s[x, y, z] /= np.sum(s[:, :, z])`
ex:

```
x, y, z = s.shape
s1      = s.copy()
for i in range(x):
    for j in range(y):
        for k in range(z):
            s1[i, j, k] = s[i, j, k] / np.sum(s[:, :, k])

# I use s1 cause I scare s will change after every loop 
# and np.sum(s[:,:,k]) is not a const

# pseudo-code example:
# s[0, 0, 1] = 1
# sum[:, :, 1] = 117  # sum of 2nd column
# then
# s[0,0,1] = 1/117
# repeat with x*y*z-1 point remain
```

i has try to use `np.fromfunction` but if run too slow. my code ex:

```
def f(x, y, z):
    result = s[x, y, z] / np.sum(s[:, :, z])
    return result
s1 = np.fromfunction(np.vectorize(f), (a, b, c), dtype='int') 
# a, b, c is shape of the array
```

Can I complete this with faster ways without for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```
s/s.sum(axis=(0, 1), keepdims=True)
```

or equivalently

```
s/np.sum(s, axis=(0, 1), keepdims=True)
```

Argument [`axis`](https://www.sharpsightlabs.com/blog/numpy-axes-explained/#:%7E:text=NumPy%20axes%20are%20the%20directions,along%20the%20rows%20and%20columns.) specifies the dimensions the [`sum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) is performed along. [`keepdims`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40927156/what-is-the-role-of-keepdims-in-numpy-python) allows the result of the summation to keep its original [dimensionality](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ndim.html) – `3` in the current case – which makes the division [broadcast](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html)-gnostique.

Comment: it's seem wrong, can you watch my for loop, i have edited it

Comment: @robocon20x Indeed, I was summing over the wrong hyperplane. See edit, which henceforth reproduces exactly the result of your 3-nested loop. Any question ?

Comment: thanks, it worked. I have 2 more question about numpy, can i have your discord or facebook? Cause i don't want to create 2 more thread...

Comment: or i will post it late. thanks

Comment: @robocon20x do not hesitate to post your questions on SO. Especialy that I may not know how to deal with your problem(s) ;) SO's community does.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to divide all elements of the array by some value, it's enough to call the division without indexing the array.

```py
test = np.array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
                  [ 3,  4,  5],
                  [ 6,  7,  8]],

                 [[ 9, 10, 11],
                  [12, 13, 14],
                  [15, 16, 17]],

                 [[18, 19, 20],
                  [21, 22, 23],
                  [24, 25, 26]]])

print(test/np.sum(test[:,:,1]))
```

Or if you want to embed it in a function:

```py
def array_divide(inputArr):
    return inputArr/np.sum(inputArr[:,:,1])
```

Comment: test[:,:,:1] and 1 is not a const

Comment: Ah, with the edit I see the problem.  I'll have a think.